# Celery - handle WorkerLostError exception with Task.retry()

Tags: celery

I'm using celery 4.4.7

Some of my tasks are using too much memory and are getting killed with SIGTERM 9. I would like to retry them later since I'm running with concurrency on the machine and they might run OK again.
However, as far as I understand you can't catch WorkerLostError exception thrown within a task i.e. this won't won't work as I expect:

```
from billiard.exceptions import WorkerLostError

@celery_app.task(acks_late=True, max_retries=2, autoretry_for=(WorkerLostError,))
def some_task():
   #task code
```

I also don't won't to use `task_reject_on_worker_lost`  as it makes the tasks requeued and max_retries is not applied.

What would be the best approach to handle my use case?

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Gal

Comment: So what is going to run that task if worker is not working any more? More precisely, what is going to handle that exception?

Comment: @DejanLekic as I understand it, you can catch the error on the main thread of the celery, this is the one that manage the pool of processes within a worker. I saw that you can use the on_failure() hook to catch this. But again, i'm not really sure what's the best approach here.